# All USB ports without power and not recognizing any device after booting to windows 10 after change in registry

Tags: windows-10

I have a problem with my pc after I made one change at the registry. Like in [this tutorial](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-enable-write-protection-usb-devices-windows-10) I changed my registry to be able to recover a USB stick with permission issues.
But soon after I made the changes, my PC wansn´t able anymore to recognize any USB stick either in explorer nor in diskpart via CMD. Thats why I removed the whole `StorageDevicePolicies` folder from the registry.
But now comes the tricky part: After booting the PC again, my mouse and keyboard doesn´t get recognized anymore. I was able to check with a USB-charger that there is no power on the ports after booting to windows. When inside BIOS/UEFI the mouse and keyboard is working fine and also the USB-charger gets power.
I also made sure that all ports are enabled inside UEFI/BIOS.
I also tried to add the folder and key like mentioned in the tutorial again without success. I also tried to run a recovery stick using `sfc /scanfs` in the console. This also didn´t solve my problem.

**How am I able to get my USB ports working again without setting my pc up from scratch?**

**EDIT**
I´m not able to access my PC at the moment but I can boot into a recovery win10 stick using the cmd line

**EDIT 2**
I was able to use an old PS/2 keyboard to enter the device manager. It seems that i have just one entry: *Intel(R) USB 3.0 eXtensible-Hostcontroller - 1.0* but I have like 6 or 7 ports at my mainboard.

Comment: why the downvotes?

Comment: That's why you don't go poking around the registry if you don't know what you are doing.

Comment: Reinstall Windows 10 from USB/ISO, keeping files and applications.